# Share code across two apps in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I've two apps that actually share the same codebase (inside the src folder) except for a few configurations. The current folder structure looks like this:

```
├── app1
│   ├── android
│   ├── index.android.js
│   ├── index.ios.js
│   ├── ios
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
└── app2
    ├── android
    ├── index.android.js
    ├── index.ios.js
    ├── ios
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    └── src
```

Inside `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` I'm requiring the modules from the src/ folder with e.g. `import MainView from './src/mainView';`

This way I've to maintain the same codebase in two different locations which is certainly not ideal.
That's why I'd like to have a folder structure similar to this:

```
├── app1
│   ├── android
│   ├── index.android.js
│   ├── index.ios.js
│   ├── ios
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── package.json
├── app2
│   ├── android
│   ├── index.android.js
│   ├── index.ios.js
│   ├── ios
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── package.json
└── src
```

Unfortunately the require calls don't resolve the path correctly with this structure. 
When I use `import MainView from '../src/MainView'` the following error message appears:

[image: error]

Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve the same problem.

A possible solution would be to use a symbolic link in each of the app directories to the external src directory. I've yet to test this out.

Comment: Dug a little deeper, I believe this can be achieved with 'npm link'. Check out this article: http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears

Comment: I was thinking so too, but I don't think that's possible with the RN Packager. See the discussion I posted in my answer.

Comment: You're right, I couldn't get this work. Problem I had was the shared component I pulled out had dependencies on RN/React, and the packager complained about conflicts (RN being loaded twice) when I installed it in the original project. At a loss here with this one.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot of discussion on [this use case here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/637). I do not believe this possible if you want to run the packager with `watchman`. Even with the newest version of RN people are still reporting issues.

Depending on your use cases, one option that has worked for me is to create a separate npm repo for the shared files between our apps, and add it as a dependency to both (change in code won't break apps that already use it). It also helps from the whole versioning perspective too. This could be a private GitHub repo (what we use) since you can use [GH repos for dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

Comment: Is it possible to get this to work if both the package and the main project have a dependency on RN? I was getting an error in the packager about both trying to register the same components.